# Improve useEffect mutating array objects and get difference beetween

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help to see if I can improve this code that I have, first I describe the final result that I hope and maybe this way you can find how to improve a little this useEffect:
I need to receive that data object, compare it with one previously stored in localstorage, and compare them to see if there is any new record in that object, if it finds new data, extract them, add the isNew property only to those key that found new and create a new array with the data I received and newArray that includes the modified data.

```
const localStorageKey = 'laboratoryData'
  const oldData = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      if ([null, undefined].includes(oldData)) {
        localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(data.data))
      } else {
        const arrayIsEqual = (data, oldData) => {
          data.data === oldData ||
            (data.data.length === oldData.length &&
              data.data.every(
                (f, i) => f.id === oldData[i].id && f.name === oldData[i].name,
              ))
        }
        if (arrayIsEqual) {
          localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(data.data))
        } else {
          const diff = data.data
            .filter((x) => !oldData.includes(x))
            .concat(oldData.filter((x) => !data.data.includes(x)))
          const newArray = diff.map((obj) => ({...obj, isNew: 'true'}))
          const finalArray = {...data, ...newArray}
          localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(finalArray))
        }
      }
    }
  }, [data])
```

Maybe i`m duplicating some code or missing a custom hook with a better performance

Thanks!

Comment: You don’t need an effect. This is an event.

Comment: can you give me dummy data for `data` and `oldData`?

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your data and based on your code snippet, hopefully your `data.data` and `oldData` are always be arrays of objects that have always have key `id` and `name`.

```js
const localStorageKey = 'laboratoryData';
const oldData = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!data) return;
    if (!oldData) {
        localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(data.data));
        return;
    }
    if (data.data.length === oldData.length && data.data.every((d, i) => d.id === oldData[i].id && d.name === oldData[i].name)) return;
    const newData = data.data.filter(d => oldData.findIndex(od => od.id === d.id && od.name === d.name) === -1).map(d => d["isNew"] = true);
    const finalArray = oldData.map(od => od["isNew"] = false).concat(newData);
    localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(finalArray));
}, [data])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! yes Data and Old are always array of objects with the same structure, i will try your answer, thanks!